# Search for strongly captured references in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Although it wouldn't necessarily be a retain cycle to capture self in this context:

```
[[GlobalInstance shared] addBlock:^{
   [self doSomething];
}];
```

How would you search for occurrences of `self` being captured in blocks using Xcode? Grep would also be an idea I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that matters is whether you have a retain cycle that causes a leak. Strategies for finding leaks include:

- Implement deinit to log and watch the console.
- Run under Leaks instrument.
- Use the Memory Graph.

Comment: Howdy @matt. Love your books!! :) Now, you're kinda assuming that I'm looking for a search query that I could use in finding retain cycles -- that's not the case. My question is simply, how would you best find references of `self` within any given block? I.e, blocks that don't reference `self` on the first line, but maybe the last?

Comment: But I’m suggesting that’s not a useful thing to look for.  :)

Comment: Lol :D Oh, but I insist :D Kidding aside, here's a scenario; Say you stumbled upon a huge code base that have successfully suppressed compiler warnings by confusing the heck out of it, and you'd want to clean up some cycles - what would be a quick way to get the approximate number of occurrences where `self` is captured in any block -- so I could further filter them out by hand. I.e, I don't expect any answer to this question to plug into AST/Clang/SourceKit and actually verify the leak, instead, simply getting a rough draft list of where `self` is captured would butter my biscuit.

Comment: Also, since I have one of the best authors of iOS on the line - would you mind giving your expertise on the following scenario? Say you have a home page menu VC that references `self` in a block like above. Say that the block is async - and there's no telling on when it'll call. Wouldn't it be safer to apply the weak/strong dance here, as the user could switch pages from a navigation menu, and potentially allocate more than one home page VC - which would potentially have catastrophic consequences?

Comment: Yes, perhaps, but I still think the best thing to do is what my answer suggests, namely caveman debugging to track allocation and deallocation of view controllers and other dubious objects as the app runs.

Comment: That's completely fair @matt. It's just very tricky to do when some VCs/objects are only accessible through certain A/B flags. Plus, even tricker when the code base is huge.

Comment: Yes, but my suggestion is that you can’t _think_ your way out of this situation. Merely looking at the code won’t do. The app needs to run; you need _facts_. Perhaps you can write UI tests to exercise every part of the app and so get the needed logging, for example.